# Long Wait time in header 200 with wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How can I reduce the wait time? sometimes it's over 5-6 seconds, please see here: https://tools.pingdom.com/#59ebd2b2c6000000

I am using AppServ v2.7
please help, i am already using gzip compression, and plugins to improve my page speed but its taking longer than 9s to load
thank you

Comment: Pingdom gives you a classification on different areas. Analyze in which ones you have a lower grade and search for ways to solve them.

Comment: Can you give more details, esp. if you think your system is slow, wordpress instances (in general) or this one particular instance you are troubleshooting is slow? I tend to think this belongs in ServerFault.com... but won't flag it without more detail.

Comment: I am using a Core i5 8th gen, 16GB ram + ssd for hosting. I only have a small mysql database running on it, i have tested with Pingdom closest server to my host

Answer (score 1):

This might be a complex of activities, I ended up in those for my wordpress blogs:
-moving from hosting to dedicated
-switching from apache to nginx
-using CDN
-using minifiers
-using a nginx frontend config to connect to varnish which connects to nginx backend config
-switching from php5.6 to php7.2
-fine tuning php and nginx and varnish configs
-enabling gzip
-using browser cache

Comment: I will try switching php version, i am worried because my header is only 26kb but the wait time is over 4 seconds.

Comment: It's not only about size. Basic hosting usually comfortably handling 75 requests/sec. Your page makes 94 requests. 2 users will cause 186 requests. And so on. The more users, the more requests coming, so they wait to get served. You should either cache some files and serve from CDN or get a powerful server. Optimization matters and is cheaper. Though you can really optimize on dedicated, not on hosting.

Comment: I am hosting it locally, I have a CPU at home running 24/7, can that be an issue?

Comment: Can't tell about your PC, but the software you choosed is outdated. Do you use it on Windows? You better be getting a clean Linux without any other software for pure web server setup with the latest possible solutions.

Comment: Yes, I am using AppServ for Windows, I just updated my php from 5.2 to 7.1, the wait time is a little shorter, however i cant switch to linux because some of our apps are only supported in Windows

Answer (score 0):

can you describe more what your is in between your app and the served request? i.e are you using an app based page cache like WP total cache?

are you using a reverse proxy cache like fastly or varnish? Are your assets being served from a CDN like S3?  do you have an opcode cache on the server?

tending to all of these issues can be time consuming.

One faster 'trick' can be to move your nameservers to cloudflare DNS, and use their free caching layer to see if what kind of easy performance gains you get.

Another good diagnose method can be combo of google page speed insights along with chrome dev tools, network tab, where you can see timing request graph and potential bottlenecks. 
maybe there is something obvious like trying to serve uncompressed 4MB images.

note that none of these will necessarily address your root issue. WP is actually not that slow in vanilla format until we start adding various plugins to it. 
the final solution would be doing a deep dive into your code using callgraphs and tools like webgrind to analyze, WP dev and theme are very prone to inefficient DB queries, and multiple redudnant 'loop' instantiations.

Comment: Yes, I am using cloudflare nameservers and using their caching layer. I just checked my site in gtmetrix and it shows that wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=module_viewed is taking around 3 seconds (wait time), how can I fix that issue?

Comment: i don't know offhand what that action does, i doubt it's in core. track down the module_action action and look at that code. if it's doing some heavy lifting, try wrapping this in a custom transient cache assignment

Comment: i updated php to ver 7.1 from 5.2 and the load time got a bit better, around 2s less. I am new in this, how do you track module_action?

Comment: look through your code for module_viewed, it will probably look something like `add_action( 'wp_ajax_module_viewed', 'module_viewed' );`  then module viewed will be defined as a function. probably this function is defined by a plugin, so you may want to determine whether what it's doing and whether ii's really needed. 
you can unset this action using something like `remove_action( 'wp_ajax_module_viewed', 'module_viewed' );` this need to be called late, i.e. in functions.php

Comment: even if the functionality is critical, and need to go back in, if you've shaved 3 seconds  off load time, then you're at least zeroing in on your issues.